# How can I hide the Windows 7 logo in the taskbar?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, taskbar

I have a WPF window that goes fullscreen, and I have made every attempt to make it truly fullscreen. WindowStyle is None, WindowState is Maximized, Topmost is true, etc. I even used p/invoke to hide the taskbar when the window is loaded and make it appear again on exit. The problem I have is when, for example, I play a video that replays once it finishes, the third-party program that plays the video pops its window up while also flashing its taskbar button. I can ignore the window since my Window has the Topmost property set to true, and I can also ignore the flashing taskbar icon/button since the taskbar is hidden, BUT the circly windows 7 logo appears on the left bottom corner no matter what. How can I disable that, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [example at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FullScreenDotNetApp.aspx) works with Windows 7.